# Vim Shortcuts or plug-ins for the following

Tags: html, css, c, vim, code-completion

I have been using the Sublime editor and is making a switch to vim (Because I have to) . I have heard that Vim is the best editor there is, if you can master all the shortcuts. Given below are some of my needs. Please tell me which shortcut/plug-in  I should use to achieve them.

1. Switch-case statement in C : I need like 10 cases. So How can I add them quickly? Is there something like `case n:10+` ?
2. Curly Bracket completion : I need an auto closing curly bracket `}`. Same need with parenthesis.
3. In CSS : Code completion for properties.
4. Code shrink option : In Sublime u could shrink the code present in a block (like a function or loop) by pressing an `>` like symbol to the left of line number. Is this possible in Vim?
5. Any other shortcut / plug-in that programmer ( C, C++, php, CSS, HTML ) can use to increase his/her productivity.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "(Because I have to)" That would be a first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Switch-case statement in C : I need like 10 cases. So How can I add them quickly? Is there something like case n:10+ ?*

   ```
   ocase :<CR>break;<Esc>
   9.
   ```

   See `:help repeating`.

   Take a look at [SnipMate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) or [Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), though.
2. *Curly Bracket completion : I need an auto closing curly bracket }. Same need with parenthesis.*

   That "feature" is not *that* useful but if you didn't already grow tired of it, you can find [a good list on the Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters#Plugins)..
3. *In CSS : Code completion for properties.*

   It's built-in. Try `<C-x><C-o>` after a couple of characters. If you don't like the default `<C-x><C-o>`, create your own with:

   ```
   inoremap <key> <C-x><C-o>
   ```

   See `:help key-mapping` and `:help key-notation`.
4. *Code shrink option : In Sublime u could shrink the code present in a block (like a function or loop) by pressing an > like symbol to the left of line number. Is this possible in Vim?*

   That feature is universally called "folding". You can close a fold with `zc`, open it with `zo`, toggle it with `za` and much more. See `:help folding`.
5. *Any other shortcut / plug-in that programmer ( C, C++, php, CSS, HTML ) can use to increase his/her productivity.*

   Learn Vim before looking for plugins.

Comment: Thank you. I am thorough with the basics of vim.

Comment: I'd recommend "surround", and either Taglist or Tagbar, for any coding. Other than that it really comes down to preferences...there are a LOT of good plugins out there and you won't ever find a definitive list of "must have" plugins. Such a list would be off-topic on StackOverflow anyway. There is a software recommendations stack exchange where that is on-topic: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

1. With a ctags database correctly configured and up-to-date, if your `switch` is on an enum, then [lh-cpp](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp_Enums#switch-case_generation) provides (through mu-template) the `CTRL-X_se` mapping that will generate your switch-case. If your want to generate it from integers, it will be possible (but a little bit tricky without mappings/commands to encapsulate it)

   `:call MuTemplate('c/switch', {'values':reverse(range(1,5)), "name": "foo"})`
2. lh-cpp embeds lh-brackets that'll offer a [nice brackets support](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp#Brackets).
3. (SO renumbers 4 to 3 if I write no "3." -> this empty and useless answer)
4. This is called folding in Vim. Usually people are using `syntax` or `indent` `foldingmethod`. I got tired of it and reworked and old [plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/VimFold4C) for C and C++ -- the plugin still needs many improvements.
5. There are many. In C and C++ YouComplete is a must have. Then I use my plugins to integrates CMake, have a project notion. Other people use other things. There is no definitive answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you. Can you send me link about this ctags database please. I can't digest all of it. Any cheatsheat or reference would suffice

Comment: You'll need a software like _exuberant ctags_ installed. Then, For your given project you'll need to tell vim where to find the tags files (`:h tags`). And regarding C++, I generate my ctags database with the following options: `--c++-kinds=+p --fields=+imaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++` (and I do it through 2 plugins: one for project management, and one for generating ctags DB, plus some tuning)